Android is not detecting Wifi connection while sleeping
I have an issue in the following use case when working on Android 12 embedded device.

The device has mandatory 24 hour reboot due to PCI regulation
At the moment of reboot, if the WiFi is not available, the device goes to sleep without WIFI connection up.
Only after waking up the Android device, the WIFI connection will be reestablish.

How can I force the device to reestablish WIFI connection, if available, even while sleeping?
Similar device, running Android 9, does not behave this way. Wifi connection is reestablished right after it becomes available, even while the device is sleeping.
I have tried to add WifiLock to my app, which is running, but with no luck, same behaviour:
val wifiLock by lazy {
    (getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "Controller:WifiLock")
}
wifiLock.acquire()
wifiLock.release()


Android is designed to run on battery powered devices with user interaction. Therefore Wifi scanning is reduced with screen off. How long have you waited for the Wifi reconnection?

The android device did not reconnect to wifi for 2 days (whole weekend), it was left "lying" on friday evening and only connected on monday morning when user woke it up. The Wifi was available both days from 7 till 22. The background tasks, which requires "connected network" did not happen at all - "ping" to call home once an hour and "maintenance" for SW updates and parameters once in a day. Those both executed right after the user woke the device up.
